# Why isn't my json data displaying with JsonView?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, api, getjson

I'm trying to display this code with JSONView but won't display when calling the data from inside the api callback function, but will display non api data when placed outside the callback.

```js
// Call FreeGeoIP API to get browser IP address
$.getJSON('https://freegeoip.net/json/', function(data) {
  var ipaddress = data.ip;

  // Get browser language
  var language = window.navigator.language;

  // Get software
  var software = window.navigator.appVersion;
  var regExp = /\(([^)]+)\)/;
  software = regExp.exec(software)[1];

  // Add data to obj
  var obj = {
    'ipaddress': ipaddress,
    'language': language,
    'software': software
  };

  // Write obj to document
  $('body').html(JSON.stringify(obj));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: What do you mean? Your code works. Do you mean it does not work in JSONP calls?

Comment: It works. What is the error in your console? ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT? You may need to disable AdBlock if you're using one - it blocks the request.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JSONView or any other json formatter detects if you are viewing json on basis on `contentType` of the `document` loaded (as set on http header).

Since you must be running this code on `client side` (browser) the `contentType` is set to `text/html` .

For the plugin to correctly format the json, it must know that what you're looking at is indeed json and it does so by reading `contentType` header.
That is why fetching json via this script shows json as text in body attribute but not picked up by the plugin.

Comment: The extension could have this option enabled by default and it took a while for me to figure out this option. Thank you so much

Answer (score 5):

**JSONView** extension or any other extensions in the Chrome browser needs permission to access file URLs if it is accessing files from your local system.
To allow:-

1. Visit `chrome://extensions/`
2. Click on `Details` button of the Extension card
3. `Switch ON` the `Allow access to file URLs`
   [image]